# Dynamic REST service declaration with Jersey

Tags: osgi, guice, peaberry

I'm trying to setup an architecture based on guice, OSGI embedded in Jetty, Jersey and I would like to able to register / remove Jersey REST services dynamically. How I can get a reference to the jersey context and add new REST services from a bundle installed dynamically.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If its just about REST services and the dynamically usage, have a look to the [Amdatu project](http://amdatu.org/components/web.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it seems quit interesting !